# Virtual screen scraping with Perl

Tags: python, perl, imagemagick, screen-scraping, mechanize

Is it possible to do virtual screen scraping in Perl, or Python? Suppose I have a login page, where once I enter the username or password, it takes me to another authentication page where I have to write what a Captcha reads. Now with Mechanize or a similar tool I can automate the first step. However, for the 2nd step, is it possible to capture a screenshot of the captcha page (virtual, since we are not really loading the page in a browser) through Perl? Once it is done, perhaps I can automate a captcha reading tool (Google has one), which will attempt to read it. (All such captcha pages will have the captcha image in a fixed place within a fixed size box, so I can use Imagemagick to crop that part of the screenshot and feed to the Google tool. It will take a few trial and error runs to find out which portion of the screenshot contains the captcha). So is it possible?

Comment: On the one hand, I'd quite like to show how easy this sort of thing is in my favourite language … on the other, automated captcha breaking is not something I'm going to get involved in without absolute certainity that it is white hat.

Comment: Well, if it is black hat, then I would have done it manually without taking recourse to Perl and stuff. I have no criminal record, I can vouch for that, nor do I intend to have one, so feel safe to share your expertise.

Comment: Why do you need to automate solving Captchas?

Comment: Nothing, in particular. The other day I was reading an article which stated that Google has a software kind of thing for deciphering captcha. So I decided to test it. Then I remembered that it will be a long process, I will have to go to the captcha page, take a screenshot, crop the captcha part, then feed it to the software, blah blah blah. So naturally my thoughts went to automation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to emulate or do anything with screen at all. Just trace where CAPTCHA requests its image data and download it yourself - you'll have ready image file.

Comment: But the image is random and will contain a different image each time. So once I have the page with a captcha in a `mechanize` object, subsequent request to the image sending page won't give me the same image.

Comment: But of course. Just as you get new image when you access CAPTCHA manually, you'll get new one with mechanize. What's exactly the problem with that?

Comment: Well, I need the page with the captcha image in it. The data I should enter in the text field below must correspond to the image above. So what is the use of requesting just a random image without the page it is supposed to be in?

Comment: 1) read page, 2) find and download CAPTCHA image referenced by this page, 3) submit this **downloaded file**, not URL, to Google service, 4) read result and use same instance of mechanize that holds page where you've read that CAPTCHA to send answer back.

Comment: Oh right. Normally whenever I right click on the captcha image and click **View Image**, it always takes me to a different image, that's why I thought that even downloading will give me a different image. But no, it gives me the same image. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My favorite captcha bypass is [deathbycaptcha](http://deathbycaptcha.com/). They have an api available for most languages. There's another service that lets you solve captchas to earn credit for future solves but I can't remember the name of it at the moment.